# Calendar and Time Zones in iOS 9.2 & OSX 10.11

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, calendar, timezone

I am confused by the time zone settings in the Apple calendars, especially by the wording.

I book a date here in Melbourne (UTC+10 ignoring DST) for an event in the Netherlands (UTC+2). I want to enter the event as 06:00 here, but really mean 06:00 in the Netherlands local time. The calendar is in iCloud.

This happens all the time when booking flights — the times are always in local time, which is, of course, appropriate.

What is the correct setting in the iPhone and on the MacBook for this to work? I think the wording has changed, but I never thought it was clear.

Currently I add the local time in the notes just in case. I was caught out in the past when the event showed the wrong time (fortunately it meant I was too early for the flight).

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a lot of time in order to have clean calendar entries for flights over multiple time zones. I couldn't find any good solution, because iOS and OS X only support ONE time zone per event (by the way, so does Microsoft Exchange).

The best solution I found was to create two events :

- One for the take-off, specified in its local time zone.
- One for the landing, also in its local time zone.

And when your phone or computer changes time zone, you have the correct local time.

In a perfect world, an event should be able to have 2 time zones (one for the start time and one for the end time). Apple could do it, but it would probably break compatibility with other applications like Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

From OS X Calendar Preferences you could turn on TimeZone settings.

[image]

[image]

Then you can select the timezone you want to display calendar time in and make entries in that timezone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that iOS 10 (currently I have 10.3.3) supports different time zones for start and end of the event. Here's a screenshot below showing how you can create a calendar entry via iOS that spans across different time zones:

[image: ss1]
[image: ss2]

Answer (score -1):

Don't you think it's ridiculous that a calendar app like that on the iphone provides no way for you to enter the time zone of an event? Di people with iphones never catch planes? The only way this can be done is for the user to change the default time zone for the whole calendar, enter the event, then restore the original setting.
You'd have thought this would be possible. In fact, support is already there: if you receive an ical appointment file in an e-mail, it's time zone specification will be used. So how come you can't enter it yourself?
The only way I've found so far is to type times into a Notes document, with the GMT offset, eg 2015-12-17 19:00+08:00 for a Singapore time. This is properly recognised as a date, highlighted as a link when you stop editing. The link invites you to create a calendar entry. When you do, annoyingly, the offset information disappears, but the time, adjusted to current local, is correct.
There is definitely room for improvement here.